# Align View to the top of a rotated TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have a `TextView` containing some text that is displayed with `android:rotation="270"` so it reads from the bottom to the top.
I have another View in the layout (a `Button`, `ImageView`, or some other simple `View` object).

I want to align the second view to the top of the rotated text like so:

[image: The layout I want to achieve]

I'm using `ConstraintLayout` so I tried the obvious, assigning `constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/text"` to the view. However, it does not align the `View` to the wanted positon but to the top of the `TextView` in its **unrotated** position. It's probably because (as you can see on the image) the bounding box of the `TextView` does not get rotated, only the displayed text does.

[image: The layout I get when using constaint alignment]

Is there any way to get the `View` to align to the **actual** top of the `TextView`, on top of its last character without hardcoding `Translation` values? Or do I have to work around it from code?

Here is my simple layout to reproduce the issue:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:rotation="270"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:text="Align me!"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/text"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found two solutions:

- **Solution 1**

Writing a simple custom control that inherits from TextView:

```
public class VerticalTextView extends TextView {
final boolean topDown;

public VerticalTextView(Context context,
                        AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    final int gravity = getGravity();
    if (Gravity.isVertical(gravity) && (gravity & Gravity.VERTICAL_GRAVITY_MASK) == Gravity.BOTTOM) {
        setGravity( (gravity & Gravity.HORIZONTAL_GRAVITY_MASK) | Gravity.TOP );
        topDown = false;
    } else {
        topDown = true;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredHeight(), getMeasuredWidth());
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if (topDown) {
        canvas.translate(getWidth(), 0);
        canvas.rotate(90);
    } else {
        canvas.translate(0, getHeight());
        canvas.rotate(-90);
    }

    canvas.translate(getCompoundPaddingLeft(), getExtendedPaddingTop());
    getLayout().draw(canvas);
}
}
```

- **Solution 2**

Usint this [library](https://github.com/rongi/rotate-layout#download). How to use?

Add in your dependencies in build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'rongi.rotate-layout:rotate-layout:2.0.0'
}
```

XML file:

```
<com.github.rongi.rotate_layout.layout.RotateLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:angle="270">    <!-- Specify rotate angle here -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
</com.github.rongi.rotate_layout.layout.RotateLayout>

<Button
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:text="Align me!"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/text"/>
```

Comment: As I'm planning to migrate the project to Xamarin, I've decided to go with the first solution. Using your `VerticalTextView` with `android:rotation="0"` and `android:gravity="bottom"` is **exactly** what I wanted to achieve. Thank you very much! Simple and elegant solution.